# 18 minutes after Shabbat time?

Tags: shabbat

I’ve heard from someone that we have 18 minutes after the time listed for Shabbat to do Muktzeh. Is this true? So let’s say it says Shabbat is to come in at 7:30. Do we have till 7:48 to do muktzeh? Is this true, or was I informed incorrectly? List sources. Thanks, really wanna know!

Comment: Did they list a time that is 18 minutes early perhaps?

Comment: Not sure. does Chabad do so?

Comment: I suspect they do. You'd have to ask them, not us, to be sure.

Comment: @Daniel you would need to confirm with makers of your particular calendar. The time Chabad.org lists is 18 minutes before shkia

Comment: I don't think it is Chabad custom @DoubleAA